# Select and order ecords between certain dates SQL

Tags: sql

I'm pretty new to SQL so please bear with me. I'm trying to write a query in SQL that will output all the records that fall within specific dates.

This is the code that I have at the moment but it doesn't work

```
SELECT 
    `Item`.`Item`, `products`.`date`
FROM
    `Item`
LEFT JOIN 
    `products` ON `products`.`ItemCode` = `Item`.`ItemCode`  
ORDER BY 
    `products`.`date` >= '2017/02/25' AND `products`.`date` <= '2017/02/27'
```

Comment: tag the specific kind of sql you're using: MySQL, PostgreSQL, etc?

Comment: your query is very clearly MySQL due to the backticks, so you should tag the question with MySQL - always specify the type of dbms

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to use a `WHERE` clause not an `ORDER BY`:

```
SELECT `Item`.`Item`, `products`.`date`
FROM `Item`
    LEFT JOIN `products` ON `products`.`ItemCode` = `Item`.`ItemCode`  
WHERE `products`.`date` >= '2017/02/25' AND `products`.`date` <= '2017/02/27'
```

`ORDER BY` is used to order the results of the query, `WHERE` is used to constrain what rows are actually retrieved by the query.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `WHERE` in order to retrieve only the rows you want and you can also use `BETWEEN` and add the `ORDER` at the end of your query:

```
SELECT `Item`.`Item`, `products`.`date`
FROM `Item`
JOIN `products` ON `products`.`ItemCode` = `Item`.`ItemCode`  
WHERE `products`.`date` BETWEEN '2017/02/25' AND '2017/02/27' ORDER BY products.date ASC
```

Answer (score 1):

Others have correctly replaced the `order by` with `where` for your query but I want to discuss another part of the query:

> I'm trying to make a query in SQL that will output all the records
>   that fall within specific dates.

Although this might not be obvious the "precision" of your data can influence how best to achieve that date range. For example if you data is precise to just a date then `WHERE products.date >= '2017/02/25' AND products.date <= '2017/02/27'` or `WHERE products.date BETWEEN '2017/02/25' AND '2017/02/27'` will choose just the 3 bold rows below:

```
    2017/02/24
     2017/02/25
     2017/02/26
     2017/02/27
    2017/02/28
```

If however your data is precise to the second (or millisecond) your get a different result, just 2 bold rows

```
    2017/02/24 12:13:14
     2017/02/25 12:13:14
     2017/02/26 12:13:14
    2017/02/27 12:13:14
    2017/02/28 12:13:14
```

To be accurate about date ranges don't use betwen or the combination >= and <= (between is just a shortcut for >= and <= ). Use this instead:

```
SELECT `Item`.`Item`, `products`.`date`
FROM `Item`
    LEFT JOIN `products` ON `products`.`ItemCode` = `Item`.`ItemCode`  
WHERE `products`.`date` >= '2017/02/25' AND `products`.`date` < '2017/02/28'
```

```
    2017/02/24 12:13:14
     2017/02/25 12:13:14
     2017/02/26 12:13:14
     2017/02/27 12:13:14 this is less than '2017/02/28'
    2017/02/28 12:13:14
```

Using LESS THAN (larger date + 1) will guarantee you get an date/time range accurate result no matter the date/time precision of the stored data.